# CustomAttribute Name Can Be Simplified

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a class with a custom attribute defined like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string name;

    public MyAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute("ClassName")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

}
```

Visual Studio highlights the line

```
[MyAttribute("ClassName")]
```

with this message:

> IDE0001 : Name Can Be Simplified.

It suggests to shorten the attribute definition to My("ClassName") which doesn't work because the attribute is not defined as "My".

This suggestion seems to be based on the way the default attributes are implemented where either MyAttribute or My could be used.  How would I implement my custom attribute to accept either My or MyAttribute like the default attributes do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically when you derive from attribute you do not use the suffix `Attribute`
when using it:

```
public class MyClass
{
  [My("ClassName")]
  public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

> It suggests to shorten the attribute definition to My("ClassName") which doesn't work because the attribute is not defined as "My".

(It's compiler magic, and it works)

> How would I implement my custom attribute to accept either My or MyAttribute like the default attributes do?

You already did, you can use `[MyAttribute("whatever")]` and it will compile just fine.

Comment: Erik - it does work! I think I had a momentary hiccup in my intellisense that was underlining "My".  Thank you for the quick response and for setting me straight.

Comment: I was intrigued when I found exactly the same thing with intellisense suggesting that 'HTMLTagAttribute' be shortened to 'HTMLTag'.  Seems very clever... I'm on the fence as to whether I like it or not!  Visually confusing.